# how do have activeadmin specific users - Rails/angularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I have a angularJS/rails application that uses Devise for authentication.
I obviously have a Users table.
I recently installed ActiveAdmin to handle my backoffice.
I'd like to have one admin user that is able to access my activeadmin page.

What would be the best way of doing that?

[EDIT]

ok so I have done this, and I get the activeadmin login screen, but when I try to login I get an error:

```
Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-20 12:45:53 +0200
Processing by Admin::DashboardController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I can't find the DashboardController anywhere.

Comment: Mike W, did my answer help? Please let me know if you have any other question!

Comment: How we could help on your question? You're not having idea how to use devise in AngularJS? Did you searched on anything that could help such as https://github.com/cloudspace/angular_devise ?

Comment: I have edited my question... a problem with the Admin::DashboardController

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveAdmin` should create an `admin_users` table for you when you do:

```
rails g active_admin:install
rake db:migrate
```

So, you can just create an admin like this:

```
AdminUser.create!(:email => 'admin@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')
```

Start the server and navigate to http://localhost:3000/admin. You should be able to login using the following:

```
Username: admin@example.com
Password: password
```

Comment: what is your problem? Please edit your question and give us more information so that we can help.